# Use HostBuilder.ConfigureServices with DryIoc container?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dryioc, microsoft.extensions.hosting

I have some class libraries that provide services to the applications I create and for legacy reasons they are tightly bound to [DryIoc](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc). That is, the *service registrations* are tightly bound, not the actual services.

If I can I would rather not just go around changing that code if I don't have to.

Creating a new ASP.NET MVC Core application I was able to use DryIoc by changing the ConfigureServices method to return an [IServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2) like this:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();

    var container = new Container().WithDependencyInjectionAdapter(services);
    return container.ConfigureServiceProvider<CompositionRoot>();
}
```

*(this is from memory so may not be 100% correct but that is not important)*

The important change was that the `void` method could be changed to return an `IServiceProvider`, which `DryIoc` can provide me with.

However, with `HostBuilder`, which I want to use for console applications, background services, etc. the method that configures services doesn't accept `IServiceProvider` so I'm not sure how to do it.

The important code is this:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => { ... })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        // configure services
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => { ... });
```

The `ConfigureServices` method above has one overload and an extension method:

- `ConfigureServices(Action<HostBuilderContext, IServiceCollection> configureDelegate)`
- `ConfigureServices(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder, Action<IServiceCollection> configureDelegate)`

There doesn't seem to be any provisions for returning or using a `IServiceProvider` or anything else that `DryIoc` could provide for me in this regard.

Is this possible? Is there a way to bridge the gap? Or do I just have to switch to using the Microsoft `IServiceCollection` for my class libraries? Since they are in use in many projects I'd rather not change just because it seems easiest in this specific instance, but if I have to, I have to.

Answer (score 5):

An answer, that was incorrect (but correct in the context of an ASP.NET application), was provided by [@Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi), and the comment thread sparked a discussion about a method `UseServiceProviderFactory` that turned out to be the solution, so thanks guys.

To use `UseServiceProviderFactory` I had to implement one class myself, and add the appropriate nuget package references to my project.

Here are the steps:

1. Add a reference to `DryIoc.dll` (unsurprisingly)
2. Add a reference to `DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`
3. Change the registration code
4. Provide a custom implementation of the framework required for `UseServiceProviderFactory`

The original code looked like this:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => { ... })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        // configure services
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => { ... });
```

Here's what to use instead:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => { ... })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddOptions();
        // configure services
    })

    //////////////////// ADD THIS vvvvvvvv
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new DryIocServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureContainer<Container>((hostContext, container) =>
    {
        container.Register<...>();
    })
    //////////////////// ADD THIS ^^^^^^^^


    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => { ... });
```

Then supply this implementation of `DryIocServiceProviderFactory`:

```
internal class DryIocServiceProviderFactory : IServiceProviderFactory<IContainer>
{
    public IContainer CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
        => new Container().WithDependencyInjectionAdapter(services);

    public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(IContainer containerBuilder)
        => containerBuilder.ConfigureServiceProvider<CompositionRoot>();
}
```

The `CompositionRoot` class above is resolved during configuration and the constructor can be used to configure the container. A dummy-class that does nothing can be used.

Comment: Note that the part about `ConfigureServices` is optional if you don't actually register any services there, but some parts of the Microsoft dependency injection registration is still, at least to me, a bit black magic so some parts will still depend on registering services through the IServiceCollection, such as configuration.

Comment: Also note that the calls to various configuration methods in my examples is only part of the things you can configure and call into, and these things are still required if, say, you want to configure the hosting environment, provide appsettings.json, and similar.

Comment: It may be shortened more to extension method `UseDryIoc()` or couple of methods, including the one with composition root. New nuget package may be?

Comment: Personally I have stayed away from the compositionroot way because I've had troubles injecting the full container for registration and registering services on it, it seems to work better with `IRegistrator`, but there are methods missing on `IRegistrator` that are present on `IContainer`/`Container` so for now I've not used it.

Comment: Specifically, `UseInstance` is not available for `IRegistrator` and I haven't figured out how to coax `.Register` to register an existing instance, perhaps that is just as easy? Am I meant to use `.RegisterDelegate` to just add a shim delegate that will be called to return the existing instance?

Comment: If you are using DryIoc v3, inject `IResolverContext` in **addition** to registrator. Or use RegisterDelegate. Sure, not udeal for this use-case, will think.

Comment: I have published DryIoc.Microsoft.Hosting v1 preview package with UseDryIoc and the factory from the answer: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.Microsoft.Hosting/1.0.0-preview-01

Comment: Very nice, will definitely use that!